# Parsing out information from a description field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I am trying to parse out a company name from an email domain. Right now we are using email to case. We are using that process to trigger a flow to create a record on another object. The email is captured in the description field.

I need to capture the company name and the subject line. Company name would be the account and the subject line would become the name of the record.

I am using formula resources within the flow to capture this information. Here is how a description field would look.

Example:

```
---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: Customer<Customer@Company.com>
Date: Fri, Jun 24, 2022 at 12:43 PM
Subject: New update on customer
To: company <mycompany@mycompany.com>

TEXT


Bob Charles
Director of Operations
Company
```

This is what I have so far:

```
MID({!$Record.Description}, FIND("FROM"
```

Thats all I have so far. I know for some of these text formulas I need to give a number of characters, but Can I just have it capture everything after"@" and before ".com>"?

```
<Customer@Company.com>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
MID(
  {!$Record.Description},
  FIND({!$Record.Description}, '<') + 1,
  FIND({!$Record.Description}, '>') -
  FIND({!$Record.Description}, '<') - 1
)
```

However, this logic assumes that the From line will appear before other lines with less-than/greater-than symbols. If you absolutely are unsure if this is true, you'll end up with a very, *very* complicated function that I don't even want to *contemplate*, at least not without another cup of coffee.

Honestly, this would be a good place to use an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) so you can just leverage Apex's [Pattern Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm).